How to imply the logic of getting a shared canvas in the case of offscreenCanvas rendering?
I have an offscreenCanvas rendering logic like in this OpenLayerrs example:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/offscreen-canvas.html.
In this example, we use a simple Layer class instance and its render method to render my layers in the OffscreenCanvas. In this case, we create our own canvas to load the result of rendering, but other layers of OL, for example, TileLayer or VectorLayer, in their rendering logic create canvas too and share canvas between all layers. So we have two canvases on one page and get a bad performance. So how can I imply the logic of getting a shared canvas in the case of offscreenCanvas rendering? 
const offscreenCanvasLayer = new Layer({
        render: (frameState) => {
            if (!container) {
                container = document.createElement("div");
                container.style.position = "absolute";
                container.style.width = "100%";
                container.style.height = "100%";
                transformContainer = document.createElement("div");
                transformContainer.style.position = "absolute";
                transformContainer.style.width = "100%";
                transformContainer.style.height = "100%";
                container.appendChild(transformContainer);
                canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.style.position = "absolute";
                canvas.style.left = "0";
                canvas.style.transformOrigin = "top left";
                transformContainer.appendChild(canvas);
            }
            mainThreadFrameState = frameState;
            updateContainerTransform();
            if (!rendering) {
                rendering = true;
                this.worker.postMessage({
                    action: "render",
                    frameState: JSON.parse(stringify(frameState)),
                });
            } else {
                frameState.animate = true;
            }
            return container;
        },
    })

